# Import from Dataset to Combobox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, dataset

I have a dataset with tables that I'd like to import to a Combobox.
So basically I want to import each name of each table into my combobox.

This is for a Winform application

Would this be possible without having to add each name manually?

The reason for this is to able to select a table to later show the table in a datagrid.

Comment: Winfroms, sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: okay. you can use first solution from my answer." see my updated answer for WinForm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create Dictionary of TableName & Table (`Dictionary<string,DataTable>`) and Bind it to ComboBox's [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datasource.aspx).

Use

`DisplayMember`(To assign DisplayMember from DataSource) is the item in the datasource that is displayed in the ComboBox items.

`ValueMemeber`(To assign ValueMember from DataSource) is the item in the DataSource that use as the actual value for the items.

**Code**

```
Dictionary<string, DataTable> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, DataTable>();
foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    dictionary.Add(table.TableName, table);
}

comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(dictionary, null);
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

**OR**
 Use Linq query to create `Dictionary<string,DataTable>`

```
Dictionary<string, DataTable> dictionary = ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().ToDictionary(x => x.TableName, t => t);

comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(dictionary, null);
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Here `Dictionary` used as DataSource. `Dictionary` have two property `Key` & `Value`. Key(TableName) used as DisplayMember & Value(DataTable) used as ValueMember.

On comboBox `SelectedIndexChanged` Bind Grid `DataSource`

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
 }
```

Comment: This might sound stupid but how do I bind TableName & Table to the combobox's DataSource?

I'm still learning this and I'm new to Winfroms since I've only been working with console apps before.

Comment: Okay. first of all ComboBox have property DataSource which use to Bind DataSource. and have two other property called DisplayMember & valueMember. Here Display member is used to display value in ComboBox in your case it is TableName & ValueMember means value of selected Item. Here it is DataTable. So, You can easily get Selected DataTable on ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged. and Bind it to your Grid DataSource.

Comment: Check out this link for more information on ComboBox http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19781/A-data-bound-multi-column-combobox & http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx

Comment: The DataSource property can be set to a number of data sources, including types, objects. Check this like to learn basic about DataSource Property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datasource.aspx

Comment: @Tapy does above explanation Help to understand Binding in ComboBox?

Comment: @Tapy I think you need to learn more about DataBinding Concept in C#  and How DataBinding works, as you said your are new in WinForm. just check out these link to learn DataBinding in WinForm Application http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html & http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial & http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3665/Data-binding-concepts-in-NET-windows-forms.

Comment: @Tapy Above my Answer is a Practice of DataBinding in WinForm Application, Don't say sound stupid.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and support! I really appriciate it and I got it working!

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
mycombobox.ItemSource = mydataset.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().Select(x => x.Name);
```

Then on each ComboBox Selected Index changed event do

```
mydatagrid.ItemSource = mydataset.Tables(mycombobox.SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: do you have a solution for winforms too?